# Graphql testing context failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, graphql

> GraphQL spring boot testing
> context is empty after the context loading

> test case is not able to execute
> due to empty context loading
> i am using spring boot test context with graphql testing and jupiter testing framework
> to test the graphql test

objective
i am trying to test the graphql api endpoint fetching date from the graphql using jupiter
test framework

pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.espark.adarsh</groupId>
    <artifactId>sspringboot-graphql-crud-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-graphql-crud-example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.graphql</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-graphql-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

- test file

```
    package com.espark.adarsh;
    import com.espark.adarsh.entity.Employee;
    import com.espark.adarsh.respository.EmployeeRepository;
    import com.espark.adarsh.service.EmployeeService;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.MethodOrderer;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Order;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestMethodOrder;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlTest;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
    import org.springframework.graphql.test.tester.GraphQlTester;
    import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
    
    @GraphQlTest
    @Import({EmployeeService.class, EmployeeRepository.class})
    @TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
    public class EmployeeControllerTest {
    
        @Autowired
        EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
        @Autowired
        EmployeeService employeeService;
    
        @Autowired
        GraphQlTester graphQlTester;
    
        @PostConstruct
        void init(){
            employeeService.setEmployeeRepository(employeeRepository);
        }
    
        @Test
        @Order(1)
        void testGetAllEmployee(){
            String document="""
                     query{
                       getAllEmployee{
                         id
                         firstName
                         lastName
                       }
                     }
                    """;
            graphQlTester.document(document)
                    .execute()
                    .path("getAllEmployee")
                    .entityList(Employee.class)
                    .hasSize(4);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change the annotations

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = EmployeeController.class)
@AutoConfigureGraphQlTester
public class EmployeeControllerTest { }
```